# Redis cluster support when using HSET

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, distributed-caching, redisson

I need to know is there a way to use the HSET command in Redis cluster mode (with sharding for the same hash), because in the HSET command we are specifying a specific hash to store the data in the Redis cluster, which resides in a specific hash slot inside a specific node, So with these aspects, I need to know any alternative way achieving this without compromising the HSET functionality in Redis.

Comment: Can you please edit the question, it's not clear.

Comment: edited @GuyKorland

Comment: Did you check Jedis docs? You should look for JedisCluster